# Decision tree learning: Basic idea

Tags: machine-learning

As given in the textbook **Machine Learning** by *Tom M. Mitchell*, the first statement about decision tree states that, "Decision tree leaning is a method for approximating discrete valued functions". Could someone kindly elaborate this statement, probably even justify it with an example. Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: Start with [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). It will give you a good approximation of what decision trees are and how they can be used with machine learning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a simple example, consider observations rows with two attributes; the training data contains classification (discrete values) based on a combination of those attributes.  The learning phase has to determine which attributes to consider in which order, so that it can effectively do well in achieving the desired modelling.

For instance, consider a model that will answer "What should I order for dinner?" given the inputs of desired price range, cuisine, and spiciness.  The training data will contain your history from a variety of restaurant experiences.  The model will have to determine which is most effective in reaching a good entrée classification: eliminate restaurants based on cuisine first, then consider price, and finally tune the choice according to Scoville units; or perhaps check the spiciness first and start by dump choices that aren't spicy enough before going on to the other two factors.

Does that explain what you need?